# Video capture SDKs and Frameworks for Windows

Tags: windows, frameworks, sdk, video-capture

I cannot find a list describing all of the different options for video capture in Windows.  I would like to keep this list to non-proprietary SDKs (i.e. ImageSource has their own SDK that works with only ImageSource capture cards).  To set an age limit on suggestions, everything should be able to run on Windows XP or newer. Include as much information you want about your suggestion.  Just to start things off:

1. [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Microsoft)
2. [MediaFoundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694197.aspx) (Microsoft)
3. [LeadTools Multimedia Capture SDK](http://www.leadtools.com/SDK/Multimedia/Multimedia-Capture.htm) (Lead Technologies) - Commercial
4. [Video Capture SDK](http://www.visioforge.com/video-capture-sdk.html) (visioforge) - Commercial
5. [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/) (VLC Project) - GPL

Comment: Number 2 on your list won't run on Windows XP; it's Vista and later only.

Comment: I meant that if it ran only up to Win2K that it wouldn't count.  I changed the limits to better reflect my intent.

Comment: LeadTools and visioforge are no real sdk's they are just wrappers for directshow + some custom filters from them.

Answer (score 2):

- [CMU 1394 Digital Camera Driver](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~iwan/1394/) (Carnegie Mellon) - free of charge
- [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) (open source) - BSD

Answer (score 1):

One more video capture SDK is Datastead: http://datastead.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification:

- [OpenCV1.0](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) relies on [vfw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_for_Windows)
- [OpenCV1.1](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) relies on the [videoinput library](http://muonics.net/school/spring05/videoInput/))

Answer (score 0):

Just a few more:

- [Twain](http://www.twain.org/) - Mainly for scanners and similar devices, but also supported for some cameras. AFAIK Twain has its own license and is free of charge.
- [libdc1394](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libdc1394) - LGPL

Answer (score 0):

Also:

- [Medialooks MPlatform](http://www.medialooks.com/mplatform/) - for things like 24/7 video logging, time shifting, simultaneous streaming, etc. Fully integrated with Blackmagic, Deltacast and Stream Labs hardware; web cams and cameras supported via DirectShow. Windows XP is also supported.