# Capture Screen Video C# .NET in a Background Process in Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, windows, video-capture, background-process

I want to create a background low-privilege process that captures all my screen activity from my "log on" time to "log off" time of Windows XP. It should:

- render a video to some formats like avi, wmv, or any other video format.
- be "lightweight" (have low overhead) as many other processes would also be running with it
- output videos with minimal file size

I am aware of [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org) and the [Easy Screen Capture Video](http://download.cnet.com/Easy-Screen-Capture-Video/3000-13633_4-10288385.html) program,
but I don't need such software. I need a simple function or module in C# .NET so that I can integrate, optimize or customize it as per my needs. Please don't recommend software.

I know how to capture a single image as shown here:

```
 private static void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Size s = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
        bmp.Save("C:\\d.jpg");    //location to save image
    }
```

but I don't know how to get a video in some avi or different video formats.

This isn't for spyware. I just want to monitor all my daily activity once I log on and keep it in video. Then in the future it might be possible to search the recorded sessions.

These questions are similar but not what I am looking for:

[Video capture SDKs and Frameworks for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567684/video-capture-sdks-and-frameworks-for-windows)

[Alternatives to DirectShow for video capture on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542693/alternatives-to-directshow-for-video-capture-on-windows)

[How to capture screen to be video using C# .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068414/how-to-capture-screen-to-be-video-using-c-net)

[Record Video of Screen using .NET technologies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397754/record-video-of-screen-using-net-technologies)

[Video Capturing + Uploading + Processing + Streaming back - .NET & C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359789/video-capturing-uploading-processing-streaming-back-net-c)

Comment: It is not possible on Vista and later. Services are not allowed to interact with the desktop anymore.

Comment: Thanks but i have already mentioned that i want it for Win XP. To be little precise I want it for Windows XP SP2 or SP3 either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture screen to be video using C# .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068414/how-to-capture-screen-to-be-video-using-c-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a Video Stream (AVI) from a Series of Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870103/create-a-video-stream-avi-from-a-series-of-images)

I think this might be your best solution. Store all the .jpg's and create an avi from the command line at intervals. I don't see how creating video on the fly would produce a "lightweight" solution.

Comment: ya definately it wont produce a lightweight soln. but dats what the task is !